# How to get random element from array?

Tags: vue.js

I need to print random quote from `quotes`. How I can do it in Vue? Should I use `v-for` or there is better way?

```
<div class="SingleQuiteBody" v-for="quote in quotes">
...
<div class="SingleQuiteVote">
```

I mean that I need print only one random quote from entity array of quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
<div class="SingleQuiteBody">
   {{quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)]}}
</div>
```

Where `Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)` will give you one random integer between `0` an `quotes.length`. You can use some other method as well to generate a random number between 0 and length of `quotes` array.

Comment: You might want to put the random number into component data or smth, as far as `quote` will change every time one of parent components is updated.